# How to transition only the radius property of an arc d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I would like to add a transition to all the path elements in the SVG that expand only the outerradius. I am trying to create a growing effect for all these mini arcs that I make.

Once all the arcs have been made, I would like ONLY the outerradius to expand for all of them. So for example I would like all the arc path's outerradius to expand by 5 but I would like them to keep all there other properties. I tried changing the outerRadius property then calling arc again, but that resets all the other properties like start and end angle. 
Here is my codepen:
http://codepen.io/nsohail92/pen/obNRvv

```
var width = 1200;
var height = 1200;
var innerRadius = height/2.5;
var outerRadius = height/2;
var count = 0;
var startAngle = 0;
var increment = (360/16) / 100; //.025
var endAngle;

var drawArc = d3.svg.arc();
var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var svg = vis.attr("width", width).attr("height", height);

function createArc() {

     endAngle = startAngle + increment;

     drawArc
     .innerRadius(innerRadius)
     .outerRadius(outerRadius)
     .startAngle(startAngle)
     .endAngle(endAngle);

     svg.append("path")
     .attr("d", drawArc)
     .attr("fill", "#81ecb5")
     .attr("transform", "translate(600,600)");


    if(endAngle < 5) {
        count = count + 1;
        startAngle = endAngle + .02;    
    }

    else {
    var pathArray = svg.selectAll("path");
    console.log(pathArray);

    drawArc.outerRadius(550);
    svg.select("path#path_0").transition().duration(1500).attr("d", drawArc);
    return;   
    }

    createArc();
}

createArc();
```

Comment: so u r saying that on draw complete increase teh outer radius of the pie chart?

Comment: There are lots of examples of how to do this. How do those not work for you?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff there are examples on how to override the arc object with a new radius but I do not want to do that since I have distinct angle values given to each arch  in my for loop. There are example of arcTween but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do -- why are you not using the pie layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments inline

```
var drawArcs = [];//stores all the arcs
var paths = [];//stores all the paths.

function createArc() {
  var drawArc = d3.svg.arc();//make an arc object every time.
  drawArcs.push(drawArc);//push the arc object
  endAngle = startAngle + increment;

      drawArc
        .innerRadius(innerRadius)
        .outerRadius(600)
        .startAngle(startAngle)
        .endAngle(endAngle);
     //make the path
      var path = svg.append("path")
        .attr("id", "path_" + count)
        .attr("d", drawArc)
        .attr("fill", "#81ecb5")
        .attr("transform", "translate(600,600)");
      paths.push(path);
    
      if (endAngle < 5) {
        count = count + 1;
        startAngle = endAngle + .02;
      } else {
        //each drawArc increase outer radius
        drawArcs.forEach(function(d, i) {
          d.outerRadius(750);
          //to the path put the transition for new radius
          paths[i].transition().duration(1500).attr("d", d);
        });
        return;
      }
    
      createArc();
    
    }
```

Working code

```js
var width = 1200;
var height = 1200;
var innerRadius = height / 2.5;
var outerRadius = height / 2;
var count = 0;
var startAngle = 0;
var increment = (360 / 16) / 100; //.025
var endAngle;

var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var svg = vis.attr("width", width).attr("height", height); //give SVG attrs

//var arcExpand = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outerRadius + 40);

var drawArcs = [];
var paths = [];

function createArc() {
  var drawArc = d3.svg.arc();
  drawArcs.push(drawArc);
  endAngle = startAngle + increment;

  drawArc
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(100)
    .startAngle(startAngle)
    .endAngle(endAngle);

  var path = svg.append("path")
    .attr("id", "path_" + count)
    .attr("d", drawArc)
    .attr("fill", "#81ecb5")
    .attr("transform", "translate(600,600)");
  paths.push(path);

  if (endAngle < 5) {
    count = count + 1;
    startAngle = endAngle + .02;
  } else {
    drawArcs.forEach(function(d, i) {
      d.outerRadius(750);
      paths[i].transition().duration(1500).attr("d", d);
    });
    return;
  }

  createArc();

}

createArc();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks but in my question I asked how to do this by ONLY changing the outerRadius property. I don't want to override the entire arc object because I give distinct start/end values to each arch.

Comment: check now in edit section.. i am changing the arc's outerradius only..updated teh plunk as well

Comment: This will not work because of the unique start/end angle values I have given to all the arcs. I end up getting this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'startAngle' of undefined

To help can you give me an example of multiple archs with different start and end angle values and a function that ONLY changes the outerRadius value of the archs?

Comment: i see that you are not using any pie layout? do you have any data for the pie?

Comment: This is another example of just updating the arcs outer radius http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/wQXCL/229/

Comment: that does not work. To help I have created a codepen to show you what's happening. Please keep in mind that I have multiple arcs.
http://codepen.io/nsohail92/pen/obNRvv

Comment: Changed my answer as per the codepen you posted, working code with the answer.

Comment: CodePen is broken: Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined 
 at pen.js:-5

Answer (score 0):

We can give id to each path and we can call separate transition for each one

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 400)
    .attr("height", 400)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(100,100)");

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(20)
  .outerRadius(20)
  .startAngle(0)
  .endAngle(Math.PI);

svg.append("path")
  .attr("id", "arc1")
  .attr("d", arc);

arc.outerRadius(70);

d3.select("#arc1")
  .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("d", arc)
```

[Code Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/renjithgovind/3p3k83mc/)

Comment: Fiddle link is broken.